# File is getting created but data is not pushed into the file

Tags: c

I have written this C program, where it takes system calls as input like `ps -f or ls /tmp`, etc and output from the system call is pushed to a file and then from the file it reads and displays the output.

Here output file is getting created `/tmp/j` but there is no data present inside it. Can some one please help me with this issue and Thanks in advance.

My program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    enum msgtype {PROCESS_LIST_REQUEST=1, PROCESS_LIST_RESPONSE, DIRECTORY_LIST_REQUEST, DIRECTORY_LIST_RESPONSE, ERROR_REQUEST};
    struct head{
        int version;
        int msg_length;
        int header_length;
        enum msgtype msg_type;
        char data;
        char *reqtype;
    };

    struct head *buf;
    char buff[10];

    buf = malloc((sizeof(struct head)));
    buf->reqtype=malloc(40);

    char req[10];
    printf("type ps -f on the console \n");
    fgets(req, sizeof(req),stdin);
    buf->reqtype = req;
    printf("%s" , buf->reqtype);
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s>/tmp/j", buf->reqtype);
    printf("%s \n",buff);
    system(buff);
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char c;
        fp = fopen("/tmp/j", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
            printf("File doesn't exist\n"); 
        else
        {
            do {
                c = getc(fp); /* get one character from the file*/
                putchar(c); /* display it on the monitor*/
            } while (c != EOF); /* repeat until EOF (end of file)  */
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `/* display it to the monitor*/` is a rather weird comment because `putchar` write to standard output which isn't necessarily a monitor all the time.

Comment: file "/tmp/j" is opened for reading. Where is it written to ?

Comment: @self yeah I have put it just to understand myself, sorry about that.

Comment: @Ramana " j" is the name of the file and "tmp" is the folder name. It is written to the file with name "j".

Comment: The code here seems to be reading from this file. But the question and the comment talk about writing to this file.

Comment: "pushed to a file". Can you point out which line of the code does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

1) Allocate some memory greater than 10 for your buff. 10 is not enough. Your string is exceeding the size of 10. I made it 20 in my machine and checked.

2) `fgets(req, sizeof(req),stdin);` is reading a `\n` at the end of the string. Delete the last character. `req[strlen(req) - 1] = '\0';`

See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for man page of fgets

Comment: I am facing the problem before the program is reaching fopen stage in the system call the string `buff` which contains  `ps -f > /tmp/j` should execute the `ps -f ` and push the output to the `/tmp/j` but here file 'j' is getting created but there is no data or output of the system call.

Comment: @nandan Please check by making these changes. It compiled and gave me the output